# Building a Unity with Firebase Messaging for iOS fails because of Dynamic Links dependency

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity project that is using FirebaseMessaging , this has been working fine for a while, but some combination of recent changes in iOS (12.0.1), Unity (2018.2.10f1), XCode (10.0), and Firebase (5.4.0) has spawned a seemingly endless cascade of errors, after updating to said versions of the various tools I'm now stuck with this mindbender:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDynamicLinks", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(invites_receiver_internal_ios_aa7b75b2efc3269e88f1077e55250e5a.o)

I'm not explicitly using DynamicLinks in this app, never have, anyone have any idea why I would have this dependency? Is it needed by messaging, and if so why is it not handled by Firebase package resolver?

I have completely cleared both XCode, Cocoapods and Unity caches and temp files several times, cleaned, build and re-build, completely deleted Firebase plugins and re-imported with no success...

If I import DynamicLinks it *does* work locally, but then fails on UnityCloud build with:

/BUILD_PATH/.../Pods/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Firebase/DynamicLinks/FDLURLComponents/FDLURLComponents.m:19:9: 'DynamicLinks/FDLURLComponents/FDLURLComponents+Private.h' file not found

So that's not a workaround either.

Comment: Invites depends on DynamicLinks. More details about workarounds and fix plans at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/228

Comment: Yes, that's probably the issue I see when including DynamicLinks, but I'm not using invites either, so it does not really explain why I need DynamicLinks in the first place. The Firebase SDK is a bit of a dependency mess if I may be so blunt - maybe it's time to just bundle the entire thing as "Firebase SDK" and be done with it :)...

Comment: The reference looks like invites is getting pulled in  - " invites_receiver_internal...